# Get email attachment size in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, email, smtp

Is there any way to know the size of the attachment that is being sent in an email in asp.net  c#?

thanks!

Comment: How is the email being sent?  How is the attachment added to the email?

Comment: I hate questions that have the logical answer "Yes".

Comment: @Lazarus: let me know how it is "Yes"?

Comment: @James: email is being sent by a regular email code. should i post the code?

Comment: @Xor: How it's "Yes" is because you can "know the size of the attachment". Follow the general thread here that you should post your code so we have some clue as to where you are trying to get this information, then we can narrow down the "Yes" into a more specific example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `System.Net.Mail` and attaching the file via the [`Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) class, then each attachment should have a [`ContentStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachmentbase.contentstream.aspx) property containing the actual file.  This property, of type [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), has a `Length` property (of type `long`) which gives the size of the file in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically attachments are base64 encoded in System.Net.Mail.  base64 encoding takes 3 bytes, and converts them to 4 bytes.

What you need to do, is determine the length of the attachment (either as Stream.Length, the byte[] length, or the File length), and divide it by .75.

This will give you the size of the attachment, base64 encoded for SMTP.

Comment: The number is an approximation, as the `base64` version should always be a multiple of 4 bytes.  It will not be hard to adjust this into the calculation; pad upwards to the next even 4 bytes.  Additionally, for email, there will be a line wrap (two bytes if you have CRLF line endings) for roughly every 68 characters of `base64`, depending slightly on how your base64 encoder is configured and implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I believe u can use HttpFileCollection class. It gives you access to all the files uploaded by client.
Here is the msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[`Attachment.ContentDisposition.Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.contentdisposition?view=netframework-4.8) will give the attachment size (in bytes)

```js
string smtpClientHost = "mymailsender.example.com";
string emailAddressFrom = "noreply@example.com";

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage {
  From = new MailAddress(strEmailAddressFrom)
};

mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("examplerecipient@anotherdomain.com"));

mailMessage.Body = "Email body content here...";

mailMessage.Subject = "An important subject...";

foreach(var attachment in attachments)
    if (attachment.ContentDisposition.Size < ByteSize.FromMegaBytes(1).Bytes) 
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(strSmtpClientHost);

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```